# Solr search with escaping solr reserved keywords

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

How do i query fields that contain solr reserved keywords as ":" in solr?

For instance,

```
q = 'uri:http://www.example.com'
```

throws up an error for "http://www.example.com" containing reserved word ":"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested this and it seem that simply escaping ":" like ":" does the trick:

```
q = 'uri:http\://www.example.com'
```

For my the index of my own site I tend to simply store the path of the URL though as I know the domain myself so that wasn't an issue for me before. But if you index external URLs then of course you need the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

Escape/replace Lucene reserved characters during indexing and store original value in separate field (`stored="true" indexed="false"` in schema). If you replace reserved characters with space, you'll get `http www.example.com` in indexed field and `http://www.example.com` in stored. Depending on the type of indexed field, you'd be able to query for exact value (if it is plain string) or for tokens (if it has analyzer).